# como puedo hacer que no se llene el vector si no se cumple la condicion

Tags: java

quiero que este vector de numeros impares solo se llene con entradas de numeros impares, el problema es que cuando no se cumple la condicion el espacio en el vector se llena automaticamente con 0, **necesito que me vuelva a pedir el dato hasta que sea un numero impar y no se llene con el 0. muchas gracias de antemano.**

```java
public void LlenarB(){
 Vector v2=new Vector();
 int vectorb[]=new int[10];
 int b=ent.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Ingrese numeros impares");
 for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++) {

  try {
    System.out.println((i+1)+"- Digite numeros impares");
    int a=ent.nextInt();
    if(a%2!=0){
      vectorb[i]=a;
    }    
    else
      System.out.println("no es numero impar");             
  }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("no es un numero ");
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Podrías restarle 1 a la variable i cada que no se cumpla la condiciones

Comment: Esto sucede porque en tu for estás incrementando tu variable cada iteración, se cumpla o no la condición de ser impar. Por tanto, o debes de poner el incremento dentro del if o decrementar cada que no se cumpla la condición. Personalmente te recomendaría incrementar el valor de tu variable cuando se cumpla que es impar.

Comment: No uses entonces una iteración con índices, usa un while o algo similar

Comment: else{        i--;
                System.out.println("no es numero impar");             
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("no es un numero ");  i--;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar la funcion "do while", vista la pagina: https://javadesdecero.es/basico/bucles-for-while-do-while-ejemplos/ para saber mas del tema

```
 int a;
 do {
    System.out.println((i+1)+"- Digite numeros impares");
    a=ent.nextInt();
} while (a%2!=0);
```

lo que va hacer es pedir números hasta que cumpla la condición que sea impar

Comment: Cuando termine el ciclo do-while va a dejar de existir la variable a; además, ese código al compilar generará un error, pues a no va a estar definida en la condición del while.

Comment: Tienes razón @Eduardo Jiménez gracias por tu aporte